# How many people re-post their question in the correct place after accidentally posting it here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

As a lurker here on MSE, I regularly see people posting questions that were meant for another site on the network, usually by mistake. These questions invariably receive comments directing them to the correct SE site - or at the very least, informing them they're on the *wrong* SE site - and are then swiftly deleted. There's even a user-script to automatically post such comments.

I'm curious as to how many of these "lost souls" realise their mistake, one way or the other, and re-post the question on the correct site. Is there any data on this, or any query I can run to get data on this?

Comment: 6 - 8 of them. I imagine it's a little tricky to get real numbers on this, as questions aren't necessarily exact matches, and there's so many sites and time gaps to consider...

Comment: Actually, my personal experience is that many questions here were asked on SO before the OP put them here or they were banned from asking questions on SO. I often found the askers of off-topic questions have accounts on SO well over 1 year or so. Sometimes I left a comment to indicate that and either the OP or the mods would delete them in minutes.

Comment: @scaaahu yes. This is my experience as well. Most "lost souls" are from SO, desperate to find anyone to answer their off-topic question.

Comment: I hadn't realised how frequent those occurrences were, but [I think you may be right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338752/461068).

Comment: Well, some cross post here at MSE if they don't get an answer on Stack Overflow... (yes, Stack Overflow main, not Meta Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm curious as to how many of these "lost souls" realise their mistake, one way or the other

Rest assured: 100% of those who *come back* to check on their question realize that. Because they see their question is closed. And that it was either moved to another site, or simply deleted, maybe with feedback "A) you are wrong here, B) try over there".

But you can also be sure that a small percentage of such OPs ... don’t even come back. People that just dump blatantly off-topic content didn't find it worthwhile to even spend 5 seconds upfront to understand what they are doing. Therefore it is also very hard to predict how they continue from that point on.

---

<sup>And beyond that, from a person spending a lot of time on Stack Overflow: besides *generic curiosity* I do not see much value worrying about the fate of these people. When your community sees hundreds of low quality questions per day, and you realize that many new users really don't care about their requests ...</sup>

<sup>At some point, I decided to focus my energy on those new users that show at least some effort with their requests. In the end, volunteer "resources" are limited, thus a need for priorities. I am sorry to say that, but at least for me, the priority for "helping blatantly off-topic postings to a better place" is very low.</sup>

Answer (score 10):

For many of these questions, there is no correct site, because they’re too broad, vague, or opinion based in their current form. And that’s often why these questions end up here: the author got question banned from the site where the question should have been posted (with massive revisions), for asking similarly poor questions.

The lack of quality is the main reason why such questions aren’t migrated, (although the system also makes it impossible to migrate a question to a site where the user has a question ban). In the past 90 days there was only [1 migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333597/323179) to a non-meta site.

Site-specific meta questions, on the other hand, are liable to be migrated as we’ve had 29 migrations in the last 90 days to a different meta site, with only about 12% rejection.

While the 10k tools give some numbers like these for migrations, there’s not an easy way to figure out how many questions are manually re-asked.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're going to get any hard stats on this, because questions all turn out differently. The best you could probably do is find all the "lost soul" posts and search for those exact same posts on the appropriate site.

But yeah, that's going to be incredibly tedious and time-consuming to track.

Comment: And impossible for me anyway, because I don't have 10k rep and can't see them. I'd have to catch them as and when they're posted, and then check the OP's network profile to see if they re-post it, and you're right, that would be quite tedious. Thanks for the answer, though.